# Repeated-measures anova and linear mixed effects models with nonrandomized data

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, nested-data

I have data from 7 subjects (`id`) who performed 3 trials of each of 2 different kinds of movement (`Factor mov`) under 2 different medication states (`Factor med`) while EMGs were being recorded. Say the dependent variable is the average amplitude during movement of the rectified EMG averaged across the 3 trials, and let's call this `amp`. There was no randomisation, each subject performed each kind of movement under each medication state. I want to test the movement kind and medication effects on amplitude and I have the following 3 questions:

(1) In this design, should `id` be called a factor? If so, is this a 2x2x7 factorial design?

(2) Is this design what's called fully crossed? If so, i.e. there is no nesting, would this anova be invalid `aov(amp ~ mov*med + Error(id/(mov*med)), data=myData)`? According to this [blogpost](http://conjugateprior.org/2013/01/formulae-in-r-anova/), `Error(id/(mov*med))` means that `mov` and `med` are crossed, but they are nested within `id`, which would be wrong in a nonrandomised design. Is this right?

(3) Is it valid to use the model `lmer(amp ~ mov*med + (1|id), myData)` with a nonrandomised design?